# Adjective "grim"

Tags: meaning

When we are talking about "grim", do you attribute these two meanings to people, "to look very serious" and "unpleasant and depressing"?

Example:

> He looked so grim.

Would it be "He looked very serious" or "He looked unpleasant and depressing"?

Perhaps the context would explain this, if these 2 meanings can be used with people.

Comment: http://onelook.com/?w=grim

Comment: With such a sentence without context it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grim):
>
> 1. stern and admitting of no appeasement or compromise: grim determination; grim necessity.
> 2. of a sinister or ghastly character; repellent: a grim joke.
> 3. having a harsh, surly, forbidding, or morbid air: a grim man but a just one; a grim countenance.
> 4. fierce, savage, or cruel: War is a grim business.

As you can see by the definitions of *grim* from dictionary.com, either one could be right. You'd have to determine the correct meaning through context.